# MVC Async error - The asynchronous action method 'Complete' cannot be executed synchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am using MVC4 with VS 2010. I have an async action that I am trying to get working. My controller inherits from AsyncController and I have the ~Async and ~Completed methods. I am able to execute my async action correctly in a sample test project. But when I run it as part of my core web app it get this exception

[InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method 'Complete' cannot be executed synchronously.]
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +133
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39

I am using Unity for Dependency Injection, ActionAttributeFilters and MVCSiteMapProvider,  I am wondering if one of these is causing the above issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**The whole stack trace**

```
[InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method 'Complete' cannot be executed synchronously.]
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +133
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10() +129
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +978122
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +978400
NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeActionWith404Catch(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) in c:\Users\Andrew Davey\projects\opensource\NotFoundMvc\src\NotFoundMvc\ActionInvokerWrapper.cs:40
NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) in c:\Users\Andrew Davey\projects\opensource\NotFoundMvc\src\NotFoundMvc\ActionInvokerWrapper.cs:21
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +40
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the NotFoundMVC Lib cause this problem. uninstall this package you will get work fine!

Comment: In what way does it cause the problem?

Comment: The latest version of NotFoundMVC has support for async