# Glimpse 1.4.1: No data has been found

Tags: glimpse

I installed Glimpse.MVC4 into an existing MVC4 project. Glimpse.axd works and I get the icon in the bottom right corner. However there is no data.

Installed it into a 'File > New Project > MVC 4 > Internet' and there is data.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `NotFoundMvc` doesn't play well with asynchronous action methods (even if the action methods are not `async`, the `ActionInvoker` on the controller classes is by default the `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`)

There seems to be a somewhat [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007696/mvc-async-error-the-asynchronous-action-method-complete-cannot-be-executed-s)

I took a deeper look into Glimpse and it seems to be related. The `AsyncActionInvoker` in Glimpse isn't being executed properly after installing the `NotFoundMvc 1.2.1 NuGet package`, which results in the nullable `ActionExecutionTime` property of the `MvcDisplayModel` not being set, which in his turn results in an `ArgumentNullException` being thrown when accessing the `Value` of that property inside the `MvcDisplayModelConverter.Convert()` method.

**To summarize**: it seems that the bug is inside the NotFoundMvc and not in Glimpse (although accessing the `Value` property of a nullable property without checking, might be tricky)

**Update**: In the meanwhile Glimpse released [a new version of their Glimpse.Mvc NuGet packages (1.3.2)](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/06/16/glimpse-1-4-2-released/) that handles possible missing execution times. So now you'll get some data in the Glimpse tabs, but not all data will be available due to the issue with NotFoundMvc.

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour of messing around I traced it back to NotFoundMvc v1.2.0.
If you have the NotFoundMvc NuGet package installed then Glimpse won't show you any data.

Comment: Do you think you can add an issue to https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues so we can see if this is a Glimpse thing or something NotFoundMvc is doing?

Comment: SO doesn't send notification be email on replies, or at least I didn't get it.

As you probably already know, an issue has been created on the NotFoundMvc project.