# MVC4 error "The asynchronous action method cannot be executed synchronously"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have existing working code in ASP.NET MVC3. We're trying to upgrade to MVC4, but one action method call is throwing an exception:

> The asynchronous action method 'Get' cannot be executed synchronously

I know other people have run into similar problems because I've seen posts like [MVC Async error - The asynchronous action method 'Complete' cannot be executed synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007696/90236).

The error occurs when our action invoker code calls the async action. I'll attempt to simplify the code, it kind of looks like:

```
String actionName = "Get";
AsyncControllerActionInvoker asyncInvoker = new AsyncControllerActionInvoker();
asyncInvoker.InvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName);
```

and the async methods are in a controller that is derived from AsyncController and is defined as:

```
[Url("methodname/{type?}"), HttpGet]
public void GetAsync()

[NonAction]
public Output GetCompleted(Output output, Exception ex)
```

So, it fails when AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction attempts to call an asynchronous method on a controller derived from AsyncController. Should I be calling AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction() instead? Why did this work in MVC 3 and fail in MVC 4?

I know that MVC 4 has improved handling of async controllers. [Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc) is a great article. But AsyncController still exists and its comment says: "Provided for backward compatibility with ASP.NET MVC 3". So, I'm hoping I can get my old code to continue working.

Comment: Are you overriding the `BeginExecuteCore` method of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`?  Is there some particular reason you are instantiating the action invoker yourself and invoking the action?

Comment: As for why it worked in MVC 3 and not 4, maybe this from the MVC 4 release notes: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253813  Also at the bottom of the page under "Known Issues and Breaking Changes" there is a bullet that says *"Controller.Execute method is no longer called. All MVC controllers are now always executed asynchronously."*

Comment: Is does seem like `BeginInvokeAction` is what you want to use based on looking at the MVC 4 source code in the `BeginExecuteCore` method of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

Comment: @asymptoticFault - we use our own action invoker because we built a toolkit to support restful web services on mvc 3. Our invoker handles the formatting of results and other things.

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough.  I was just trying to get some understanding of where you were coming from.

Comment: It was a fair question. I'm happy for all your feedback and suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome.  I'm afraid I don't have a specific solution for you but hopefully those suggestions will steer you in the right path.  Do you have access to the MVC 4 source code?

Comment: Good tip. Found it at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/